# Jordan forms associated with characteristic polynomials and minimal polynomials

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations, jordan-normal-form, minimal-polynomials

> Given characteristic polynomial $(x-3)^3 (x+1)$ and minimal polynomial $(x-3)^2 (x+1)$. Find possible Jordan forms of linear transformations with them.

Here is my answer:

\begin{bmatrix}
    3 & 1 & 0 &0 \\
    0 & 3 & 0 &0 \\
    0&0&3&0\\
0&0&0&-1
  \end{bmatrix}

My questions are:

1), Does it matter if I start with $3$ or $-1$ on the left (i.e. does the magnitude of eigenvalues matter in Jordan forms)?

2), Does it matter if I put "$1$" at the entry(1,2) (i.e. first row and second column) or at the entry(2,3) (i.e. second row and third column)? In the above matrix, I put "$1$" at the entry(1,2).

Comment: this is fine. I think most people would say that any given eigenvalue should be in consecutive diagonal entries, so that we can tell by eye exactly what the Jordan blocks are.

Answer (score 0):

No, it does matter in either case, but that means that you need to count the permutations of the Jordan blocks.  Thus, there are 3! = 6 possible Jordan forms.